# Google web designer - component timer doesn't show days

Tags: html, google-ads-api, google-web-designer

I want to add timer to my banner, so I followed this [instruction](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/7214799?hl=en) and everything works fine, but it shows time's left like Hours-Minutes-Seconds. And I need to show like Days-Hours-Minutes-Seconds. Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You know number of days is hours / 24, right? ;-)

Comment: I can put only target date 2029-09-09T15:53:00+07:00, but there is no option how to display..

Comment: Do you know javascript? I suspect that if you wish to extend the component, you will need to do so via javascript.

Comment: Is there any way to do it via GWD?